# Как получить все элементы TableView Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

[image: Таблица]

Доброго времени суток!
Есть `tableView`, с которого нужно получить все элементы и сделать `UPDATE` запрос в `SQLite` базу. Скажите, каким способом можно это сделать?

```
package sample;

public class mainFormController{

    @FXML
    TableView tableView;
    @FXML
    TableColumn idColumn;
    @FXML
    TableColumn surnameCol;
    @FXML
    TableColumn nameCol;
    @FXML
    TableColumn secondnameCol;
    @FXML
    TableColumn adressCol;
    @FXML
    TableColumn numberCol;
    @FXML
    TableColumn idstyleCol;
    //club
    @FXML
    TableColumn idColumn2;
    @FXML
    TableColumn descripColumn;
    @FXML
    TableColumn dateColumn;
    @FXML
    TableColumn adressCol2;
    @FXML
    TableView tableView2;



    @FXML
    public void OnExitClick()
    {
        System.exit(0);

    }

    @FXML
    public void LoadAction(ActionEvent event)
    {
        ObservableList<Clients> _list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ObservableList<Club> _list2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

        _list = Helper.GetClients("SELECT * FROM clients");
        _list2 = Helper.GetClub("SELECT * FROM club");
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Clients, Integer>("id"));


        secondnameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Clients,String>("secondname"));
        secondnameCol.setEditable(true);
        secondnameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        secondnameCol.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Clients, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Clients, String> t) {
                        ((Clients) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setSecondname(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
        );

        surnameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Clients,String>("surname"));
        surnameCol.setEditable(true);
        surnameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        surnameCol.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Clients, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Clients, String> t) {
                        ((Clients) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setSurname(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
        );

        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Clients,String>("name"));
        nameCol.setEditable(true);
        nameCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        nameCol.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Clients, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Clients, String> t) {
                        ((Clients) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setName(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
        );

        adressCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Clients,String>("adress"));
        adressCol.setEditable(true);
        adressCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        adressCol.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Clients, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Clients, String> t) {
                        ((Clients) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setAdress(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
        );



        numberCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Clients,String>("phonenumber"));
        numberCol.setEditable(true);
        numberCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        numberCol.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Clients, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Clients, String> t) {
                        ((Clients) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setPhonenumber(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
        );


        idstyleCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Clients,Integer>("idofstyle"));

        //второй колум
        idColumn2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Club,Integer>("id"));

        descripColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Club,String>("description"));
        descripColumn.setEditable(true);
        descripColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        descripColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Club, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Club, String> t) {
                        ((Club) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setDescription(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
        );

        dateColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Club,String>("dateofbirth"));
        dateColumn.setEditable(true);
        dateColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        dateColumn.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Club, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Club, String> t) {
                        ((Club) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setDateofbirth(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
        );


        adressCol2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Club,String>("adress"));
        adressCol2.setEditable(true);
        adressCol2.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        adressCol2.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Club, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(CellEditEvent<Club, String> t) {
                        ((Club) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                                t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                        ).setAdress(t.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
        );


        tableView.setEditable(true);
        tableView2.setEditable(true);
        tableView.setItems(_list);
        tableView2.setItems(_list2);    
    }

    public void SaveItems()
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вопрос больно общий, то простейшая реализация:

```
public void saveItems() {
    for ( Clients client : tableView.getItems() ) {
        //здесь надо какую-нибудь проверку, изменилось ли что-нибудь,
        //чтобы лишних запросов в базу не было
        Helper.updateClient( "UPDATE clients " +
            "SET secondname = "  + client.secondname + 
              ", surname = "     + client.surname +
              ", name = "        + client.name  +
              ", adress = "      + client.adress +
              ", phonenumber = " + client.phonenumber  +
              ", idofstyle = "   + client.idofstyle +
           " WHERE id = " + client.id );
    } 
}
```

Это при условии что в `Helper`е есть какая-нибудь реализация метода `updateClient` и НЕ используется `PreparedStatement`, что было бы неплохо:

```
updateClientStmt = connection.prepareStatement( " UPDATE clients " +
            "SET secondname = ?, surname = ?, name = ?, adress = ? " +
                 "phonenumber = ?, idofstyle = ?, WHERE id = ?" );
```

Тогда можно было бы передать все параметрами как аргументы метода, ну да ладно.
( Схему базы я естественно выдумал )

P.S. Кстати, все манипуляции с базой лучше бы производить в отдельном потоке. В `FX` есть неплохая библиотека `javafx.concurrent'.

Comment: PreparedStatement в хелпере как раз таки используется. Но я приду домой попробую вашу реализацию. Спасибо большое!

Comment: Работает. Только пришлось немного переделать сам запрос, я получал datatype ошибки.